# Producing a CSV of Cloud Bucket files

Tags: google-cloud-storage, export-to-csv, google-cloud-automl

What's the best way to create a CSV file listing images in a Google Cloud bucket to be imported into AutoML Vision?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to listen the files that are saved on a bucket you can use a [Google cloud function to listen the new files](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/tutorials/storage) and create the csv file in another bucket

For example you can use this python code as starting point, this code log the details of a new uploaded file

```
def hello_gcs_generic(data, context):
    """Background Cloud Function to be triggered by Cloud Storage.
       This generic function logs relevant data when a file is changed.

    Args:
        data (dict): The Cloud Functions event payload.
        context (google.cloud.functions.Context): Metadata of triggering event.
    Returns:
        None; the output is written to Stackdriver Logging
    """

    print('Event ID: {}'.format(context.event_id))
    print('Event type: {}'.format(context.event_type))
    print('Bucket: {}'.format(data['bucket']))
    print('File: {}'.format(data['name']))
    print('Metageneration: {}'.format(data['metageneration']))
    print('Created: {}'.format(data['timeCreated']))
    print('Updated: {}'.format(data['updated']))
```

Basically the function is listening the storage events "google.storage.object.finalize
"  (this happen when a file is uploaded)

To deploy this function on the cloud you can use this command

`gcloud functions deploy hello_gcs_generic --runtime python37 --trigger-resource [your bucket name] --trigger-event google.storage.object.finalize`

or you can use the [GCP console (Web UI)](https://console.cloud.google.com/functions/add) to deploy this function.

- selecting "cloud storage" on the trigger field
- select "Finalize/create" on the event type
- specifiying your bucket

Even you can directly process the files using Auto ML within a cloud function as is mentioned in this [example](https://www.lucidchart.com/blog/cloud/building-an-image-classification-system-part-3).